Trying to manipulate output via powershell
I use the Get-LocalGroupMembership function to get the members of the local administrator group.  The content of the $AdminGroups variable is as follows.
I want to get an output like below. how can I do that?
My desired output :
 adm_user;srv1_user

AdminGroups variable:
 PS C:\Windows\system32> $AdminGroups


Name         : adm_user
Depth        : 1
ParentGroup  : Administrators
Type         : Local
Computername : hostname1
isGroup      : False

Name         : srv1_user
Depth        : 1
ParentGroup  : Administrators
Type         : Domain
Computername : hostname1
isGroup      : True

Script :
$AdminGroups = Get-LocalGroupMembership -Group 'Administrators' -Depth 1 

$Results =  foreach($AdminGroup in $AdminGroups){
      [PsCustomObject]@{ 

      Username = $AdminGroup.name -join '; ' 
      
      }


}

$Results


the loop isnt needed, pwsh can do that enumeration for you, $AdminGroups.name -join '; '

What's wrong on (Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -join ';'? Or (Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators | ForEach-Object {$_.Name.Split('\')[-1]} ) -join ';'?

Should be pretty easy. Try this and let me know!
$AdminGroups = (Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators).name
$AdminGroups = $AdminGroups -join ";"
$AdminGroups

